# Qt: QTableView how to add a row?

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have got a QTableView with data in it. What is the simplest way to add a row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you use som YourModel to show it in YourTableView (QTableView)  should do like this:

```
YourModel->insertRow(YourModel->rowCount(QModelIndex()));
// paste some data to new row
```

update of model causes update of View

Comment: What if I had a matrix as a member property, dispatched the "Reshape" method on it (for instance, expand a 3x3 matrix to a 4x4, which dimension are set by 2 QLineEdit components) and automatically reflect this change to the view? Calling n times "insertRow()" isn't an option

Comment: Please take a look. Note that I don't have any prior experience in Qt, but I'm somewhat experienced with C++. https://gist.github.com/jkomyno/73b13e3091b7ff0b7207fd6bc1af6a95

Comment: sory, didn`t catch from first time, inherite from QStandardItemModel - so your model setRowCount, setColomnCount will work.

Comment: or in TableModel
beginInsertRows(); 
 insertRows(...);
endInsertRows();

Answer (score -3):

QTableView is model based if you don't know what model is then I suggest you read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html).

Use QTableWidget instead is much easier for a beginner and you can add a row just like this

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(0);
```

Comment: Bad answer. It does not even answer the original question.

Comment: @alphalamco post a better one I am shure the OP wild mark it properly. I can't delete the answer tough I would

Comment: not an answer, beginner or advanced, just give the answer and then give a suggestion... thx